# How to keep values of Page Items in session after branching in APEX 4.2

Tags: session-state, oracle-apex

Have a following question

How can I save the value of Items in session after I click on a button and branch to the next page and then again return back to the same page.?

Scenario

1. Created a Page and and HTML region with multiple Items one of them is a Select List Item and based on the value selected from the list rest of the Items get populated by using a DA.
2. Click on a button which submits the page and then created a Branch to go to the next page.
3. In the next page I created a File Browse Item to load the file and click on the Save button which saves data in staging table and created another branch with brings me back to the page mentioned in the step 1.
4. When I come to the 1st page the values of all the Items are NULL, even though the value of the Select List Item is the same still all the values are NULL.

Would like to know how can I display the same values as were being displayed before??

I am using ebs r12 and APEX 4.2

Thanks

Comment: Do you use a process to retrieve values on the first page, eg the automated row fetch process? Are you sure you are not clearing the cache in one of the branches?

Answer (score 0):

there might be different cases
like below

1. if you would give source as always replace and value null, page load may cause deletion of data
2. if you dont check the Fire On Page Load checkbox in your Dynamic actions menu it wont update the data of other fields depending on selectlist. only works at change of the selectlist

if you check this item it would run and may fill the data of other fields

while you are logined to developer run your application and open debug mode and check the session by opening view debug you can open debug and see the page items working flow order and inspect the changes